# how to reduce space before and after section and subsection keeping numbered sections intact. Sending you the preamble code. Thanks in advance

Tags: spacing, sectioning

```
\documentclass[manuscript,review,screen]{acmart}

%\setcitestyle{super,sort&compress}
\citestyle{acmauthoryear}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % For algorithms
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


      \newcommand{\squeezeup}{\vspace{-0.9cm}}
\setlist{noitemsep}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{1cm}
    \addtolength\evensidemargin{-.5cm}

\makeatletter
\let\origsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar{\starsection}{\nostarsection}}

\newcommand\nostarsection[1]
{\sectionprelude\origsection{#1}\sectionpostlude}

\newcommand\starsection[1]
{\sectionprelude\origsection*{#1}\sectionpostlude}

\newcommand\sectionprelude{%
  \vspace{1em}
}

\newcommand\sectionpostlude{%
  \vspace{1em}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence ''keeping numbered sections intact'' is not clear, I'll assume you want to alter globally all the sections.

As usual, in `acmart`, the command `\section` is defined in terms of `\@startsection` latex core function like this :

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
{-.75\baselineskip \@plus -2\p@ \@minus -.2\p@}%
{.25\baselineskip}%
{\@secfont}}
```

Where:

1. the length on line 2 is the skip above the title (disregard the -
   which only prevent the indeatation of next paragraph).
2. the length on line 3 is the skip after the title.

It should be enough to replace the `-.75\baselineskip` by `-.50\baselineskip` or something like this, ad similar for the afterskip.

I newer used `acmart` class, and can not compile your file, but this perfectly works in standard latex.

In any case, if you want to kepp you strange method, use `\vspace*{}` to prevent space removal by LaTeX.